# PDF-LIB ignoring "Arbitrary Mask" Adobe PDF Field

Tags: pdf-lib.js

We are using this library https://pdf-lib.js.org/ to generate PDFs from our application.

For one field on the PDF, I have set a special format for "Arbitrary Mask" that works when I copy the file and manually file it. However, it is ignored by the pdf-lib when the file is automatically generated. For reference, other formatting options selected in Adobe do work for font size and combing.

Is there a way to enable masking within this library?